# Reflector post in Italian

Tags: vocabulary

What would you call "reflector post" in Italian? It is a thing made of plastic material that can be found next to roads every given distance.

Image:
https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/reflector-post-side-street-64779193.jpg

Suggestion: posta riflettore.

Thank you.

Comment: Your “suggestions” are not always terribly useful... :-) (“Posta riflettore” doesn't mean anything, but if it did, it would seem something like “spotlight mail”, whatever that might be.)

Comment: In this context, *post* corresponds to *palo* or *paletto*.

Comment: There is also the term "paracarro" https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracarro.

Answer (score 7):

The technical term is ["delineatori di margine"](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segnaletica_complementare), but that's quite obscure even for an Italian, unless they are traffic code expert. Personally I would call them "paletti catarifrangenti" in everyday speech.

Comment: O anche solo *catarifrangenti*